# How to loop data and place it in exact where it is. With Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I'm using jQuery 3 and Laravel 5.8.

I've tried so many times for looping data and the result is wrong.
I've done in `show.blade.php`, and there's nothing wrong. But, when I loop using jQuery it makes the result different.

```
// Get Project by po id
$('#product_owner').on('change', function() {
  let product_owner_val = $(this).val()

  if(product_owner_val) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'project/get/project-po/' + product_owner_val,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function() {
        $('#loading-project').show()
      },
      success: function(projects) {
        $('#loading-project').hide()
        $('#project-list').empty()

        if(projects.length) {
          $.each(projects, function(key, project) {
            // Project Not found Message
            $('#project-not-found').hide()
            $('#project-list').append('<div class="box box-solid box-primary"><div class="box-header"><div class="box-title pull-left">' + project.name + ' - ' + project.project_code + '</div><div class="pull-right"><a href="/dev/projects/' + project.id + '" id="btn-show" class="btn btn-success" title="Detail Project ' + project.name + '"><span class="fa fa-eye"></span></a><a href="/dev/logbook/edit-project/' + project.id + '" class="btn btn-warning" id="btn-modal-show" title="Edit Project ' + project.name + '"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span></a><a href="logbook/add-new-sprint-to-project/' + project.id + '" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-modal-show" title="Add Sprint to project ' + project.name + '"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></a><a href="/dev/logbook/add-target/' + project.id + '" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-modal-show" title="Add new target to ' + project.name + '"><span class="fa fa-circle"></span></a>Collapsed Button</div></div><div class="box-body">' + $.each(project.project_sprint, function(key, sprint) {  }) + '</div></div>')
          })
          // Append Sprint in each project
        } else {
          $('#project-not-found').fadeIn()
        }
      }
    })
  } else {
    $('#project-list').empty()
    $('#project-not-found').hide()
  }
})
```

So, in this case. I want to fetch data from the projects table based on 'Product Owner [ID]'. but when I fetch the data to view, its return projects list based on Product Owner. But, here, I have sprints table that attached to projects, it's many to many relations. and Target Table that has project_id and sprint_id. The point is, I want to fetch projects based on sprints that attached to the project.

Comment: You seem allergic to semi-colons

Comment: hahaha semi-colons it's optional in javascript

Comment: It's not optional, it's just not mandatory - confusing right? Not using them forces your browser to complete some sanity checks

Comment: Codding standards should be followed at every possible way even semi-colons as well

Comment: Can you please provide an example for `projects` variable in `success` callback?

Comment: @dganenco, (https://i.imgur.com/LrVNq2N.png) this is inside variable projects, projects table has relation to sprints table and targets table.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand nothing from your image. Can you please provide it as text please?

Comment: @dganenco I apologize, this is the data (http://pasted.co/c1cfce69)

Comment: Ok, thx, is it correct? Or you are expecting other data?

Comment: no, but I just  wanna fetch project that has exact sprints

Comment: If the data being returned is incorrect, I don't see how it's the jQuery that's wrong. Surely the controller is returning the wrong data? Is the data in your blade template being called from the same method as the Ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you're fetching the right data from the model you can create a loop in the loop to list the `project_sprint` and append the inner HTML with the sprint names. You can do something like below:

```
$.each(projects, function(key, project) {
    $('#project-list').append('<div class="box box-solid box-primary">
        <div class="box-header">
            <div class="box-title pull-left">' + project.name + ' - ' + project.project_code + '</div>
            <div class="pull-right"><a href="/dev/projects/' + project.id + '" id="btn-show" class="btn btn-success"
                    title="Detail Project ' + project.name + '"><span class="fa fa-eye"></span></a><a
                    href="/dev/logbook/edit-project/' + project.id + '" class="btn btn-warning" id="btn-modal-show"
                    title="Edit Project ' + project.name + '"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span></a><a
                    href="logbook/add-new-sprint-to-project/' + project.id + '" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-modal-show"
                    title="Add Sprint to project ' + project.name + '"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></a><a
                    href="/dev/logbook/add-target/' + project.id + '" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-modal-show"
                    title="Add new target to ' + project.name + '"><span class="fa fa-circle"></span></a>Collapsed Button
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="srpint_div_'+project.id+'" class="box-body"></div>
    </div>')
    $.each(project.project_sprint, function(key2, value) {
        $('#sprin_div_'+project.id).append(value.name)
    })
})
```